# when I hit ctrl-alt-F1 i get a black screen

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, boot, upgrade

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop but when I boot it up I get the GNOME menu and then when I pick the first option, I get "Ubuntu 11.10" with five dots under it but it will go no further. I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, I get a black screen, and if I try "recovery" I get a message there is no data found.

Pressed escape instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

starting modem connection manager failed

starting CUPS printing spooler/server failed

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation is quite vague or I couldn't make out what you are saying. Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and you might get your GUI back.

Comment: im still getting nothing but can u explain the starting modem connection manager failed and the starting CUPS printing spooler/server failed